# What is meant by dc drop?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, semiconductors

What is the exact meaning of the term dc drop in transistors?
In solving the problem in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfx5j.jpg) given below , I was asked to find the dc drop across the collector resistance as shown in  [circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq5Ko.jpg) so I thought it may be voltage drop but it is not as can be seen the solution(pdf link in comments)

```
  ${Any\ Help\ Is\ Greatly\ Appreciated}$
```

[[image: circuit]
[image]

Comment: In the image of question referring fig. is actually 4.33 , the link to PDFs is http://www.ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/leph206.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRA92r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Redrawn circuit with higher voltages at top.*

It should be easier to understand if we redraw in a more conventional manner with higher voltages at the top, etc.

- Voltage at A will be equal to Vcc, the supply voltage.
- The voltage at B will depend on how much current is able to flow through Q1. This, in turn, will depend on how "turned-on" Q1 is.
- The voltage drop is simply \$V_A- V_B\$.

A quick example:

- Vcc = 12 V.
- Rc = 1 kΩ.
- Ic (the current through Rc and Q1) = 5 mA.

From Ohm's Law, \$ V = IR \$ we get the voltage drop across Rc as \$ V = 0.005 \cdot 1000 = 5~V \$.

We can, using this result, calculate \$ V_B = 12 - 5 = 7~V \$.

Comment: So basically does it means that dc drop is voltage drop?

Comment: Yes, but they've (poorly) clarified it for you by specifying that they only want you to work out the DC case and not worry about any AC signal. "DC voltage drop" would be a better way of asking.